# Silent installation of MySql as Service

Tags: mysql, windows, service, silent-installer

i need to install **MySql Server** in silent mode on **Windows**.

I run the following command for installing the server:

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe --action=install --catalog=mysql-5.6-winx64 --type=developer --product=* --config=mysql-server-5.6-winx64:passwd=MyPassword;openfirewall=true;autostartservice=true
```

This install the server correctly but **do not install** any **service**.
How can I install the MySql as service from command line?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
    `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --install`